# How many variations of the fighter class are there?

Tags: dnd-5e, character-creation, class-feature, fighter

### Constraints

- Only considering the material in the Player's Handbook.
- Not considering variation in starting stats.
- Not considering variation in race.
- Level 12 Fighter.

### Premise

Inspired by [this question regarding class variation](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/144770/is-there-really-a-lack-of-character-customisation-options-when-levelling-up).  I was contemplating the number of choices that are made when leveling up and how many different outcomes there are.  This is not considering how different each outcome is from the others.

### Question

**How many unique combinations of choices are there for skills, features, feats, attributes, and spells for a level 12 fighter?**

I'm interested in a succinct calculation of the number of different variations of a straight fighter at level 12.  Attribute point distributions, feats taken, combinations of spells for eldritch knight or maneuvers for battle master should all be considered in uniqueness.

#### Example

For example, at level 1 a fighting style is selected.  There are five options, so that starts out with five different variations.  Moving on to level 3, martial archetype is selected.  Champion is straight forward, but battle master has it's choice of different maneuvers.  The selection of different combinations gives different, albeit sleight, variations.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/92154/discussion-on-question-by-gcl-how-many-variations-of-the-fighter-class-are-there).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Two Quintillion, give or take

Assuming all we care about is what you get directly from being a Fighter. The Fighter makes four categories of decision; let's cover them one by one.

**Fighting Style**

As you say, Fighting Style is chosen at level 1, which gives **5** options.

**Starting Skills**

At first level, fighters choose two skills from a list of eight, which gives **28** options total.

**Martial Archetype**

First there's the Champion. At 10th level, Champions get a second Fighting Style; this feels like it should be four options, but since we don't care what order we get our Styles in there are only ten possible pairs, so the multiplier for this is **2**.

Next up is the Battle Master. They choose five manoeuvres by level 12, from a list of 16; that's **4368** possible choices. They also get proficiency in one of **17** sets of artisan's tools, for a total of **74256** Battle Masters.

Finally, the Eldritch Knight. By level 12 they know 8 spells; they can be any combination of 1st and 2nd level Wizard spells, and 6 of them must be Abjuration or Evocation. 15 spells exist that satisfy all these conditions, and 49 satisfy all but the School requirement. So they can have (15C6 * 49C2) + (15C7 * 49) + (15C8) = 5005*1176 + 6435*49 + 6435 = **6207630** spell choices. Add to that 3 of 16 cantrips, a total of **560** cantrip choices, and you get **3476272800** possible Eldritch Knights.

Sum the classes and you get **3476347058**.

**ASIs**

A 12th-level Fighter has 4 ASIs; if all are spent as ASIs, then the player has 8 points to distribute over 6 skills, which is 13C5 = **1287**. If 1, 2 or 3 are spent as ASIs, then the total number of choices is **21, 126 or 462**. Great.

The Player's Handbook offers 42 feats; they are also incredibly complicated. Perhaps later I will edit in an analysis of what the individual feats do to the maths (spoiler: it's hecking complicated), but for now I'm just going to pretend that each feat can be taken once and requires no decisions. So for 1, 2, 3 or 4 feats, you have **42**, **861**, **11480** or **111930** choices. Cross-multiply these numbers, and you find yourself with 2350530 + 1446480 + 397782 + 54054 = **4248846** choices here.

**Total**

Put these options together and you get: **5 * 28 * 3476347058 * 4248846 = 2.0678649e+18**. That's just a hair over two quintillion options.

## This is a bad way to prove your point

You state in the comments that "*This would be a useful point for subsequent "it's all the same" and "feat/ability trap" discussions*". This is wrong. It would not. Two quintillion is a nonsense number. It enumerates such helpful character choices as follow:

- A fighter with 14 Charisma and 15 Wisdom, and the same character with 15 Charisma and 14 Wisdom
- A fighter who took the Resilient (Strength) feat for +1 Strength and no other effect, a Fighter who took the Weapon Master feat for +1 Strength and no other effect, and a fighter who took the Heavily Armored feat for +1 Strength and no other effect
- 1364 Battle Masters who only use Precision Attack and ignore their other four manoeuvres
- An Eldritch Knight who can cast *Light*, and one who can cast *Dancing Lights*
- A Champion who put all 8 points of ASI into Intelligence

And each of these characters overlap and are repeated millions of time, along with many others. I have not done anything helpful here; I've done a fun maths problem, and this answer does not deserve a place in any halfway serious conversation.

Comment: Don't forget about background options and weapon buildouts :)

Comment: I love you for this.

Comment: I know you didn't go into full feat complications, but I want to point out just **one** feat that adds a huge multiplier - Magic Initiate has you choose between six classes, then choose two cantrips and one first-level spell from that class...

Comment: If you want to add it, I was calculating Magic Initiate and using PHB only it seems to have 8314 combinations possible (just adds to the silliness though)

Comment: Skilled (3 skills or tools) has 35C3 = 6545 possibilities

Comment: Thanks. This is useful to me.